# How can I detect a collision from an canvas element and html elements

Tags: html5-canvas

Is it possible to detect if an Canvas Element is colliding with any html on the main page? For example, I have a page with a table, an image and different buttons. Now I add an canvas element with snow particles falling down.

I want to stop the pixel by colliding with any element outside the canvas. Is this possible to detect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, sounds doable and fun :) I think a solution could look roughly like this. I'll assume you are using or can use jQuery, for a concise solution. It would still be possible otherwise, but more complicated.

```
//Look up all DOM elements that should stop the snowflakes
var $elements = $('.collider'); //Add class "collider" to relevant elements in the HTML for easy lookup

//Create an array to store colliding elements' coordinates
var elementCoords = [];

//Look up the canvas element's position
var canvasOffset = canvasElement.offset();

//Loop through all elements and populate the coordinate array. 
//Don't bother storing bottom side as snow falls from above
$elements.each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      thisOffset = $this.offset();
  elementCoords.push( { top: thisOffset.top, left: thisOffset.left, right: thisOffset.left + $this.width() } );
});

//Detect collisions inside the animation loop
while(animating){
  elementCoords.forEach(function(coords){
    snowflakes.forEach(function(snowflake){
      var snowflakeGlobalY = snowflake.y + canvasOffset.top,
          snowflakeGlobalX = snowflake.x + canvasOffset.left
      if(snowflakeGlobalY  > coords.top 
          && snowflakeGlobalX  > coords.left 
          && snowflakeGlobalX  < coords.right) {
        //Kill snowflake
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I haven't tested this but it should at least serve as an outline to a solution. If there are many snowflakes and/or HTML elements I guess performance might become an issue.

Comment: Hi Peter,
this sounds like a good solution for my problem.
And to tag elements with a class allows to decide the amount of elements to collide (also to avoid performance problems).
Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help. Curious to hear if it works out in the end :)